# List that can only contain a value once

Tags: java, list

This is most certainly a noob question, but I haven't been able to find a good answer on Google or here, so I have to ask:

What kinda list should I use in Java, when I just want a value to be added once?

The problem is that I'm doing a web technology project in college (a webshop), and I have this cloud I connect too. I can the request the customer ID´s from those who bought items in my shop. What I want to do is extract these ID´s and add them to a list. But when extracting them I get the ID returned for every item they have bought, so I want a list that can check: "This value is already in this list, do nothing", or "This ID is not in the list, lets add the ID"

Is there a list that can do this, or a way to do it with a list without it getting too complicated?

Comment: Not a List, you want a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Answer (score 5):

You want a `Set`, this is the data structure that prevents duplicates.  This is a `Collection` so you can define a function like so:

```
public Collection<MyObject> foo()
{
     return new HashSet<MyObject>();
}
```

and at a later time change the return internally to this:

```
public Collection<MyObject> foo()
{
     return new ArrayList<MyObject>();
}
```

And your API won't break.

Comment: It would probably be best to use generics here.

Comment: Is there a Set where i can automaticly get it Sorted by value? I know TreeSet can sort by Key, but i need a way to easily get the 5 objects with the highest Value?

Answer (score 2):

A Set contains every value only once.

Though, the problem with [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is that the order in which the elements were added gets lost. So if you want to preserve the order of elements, I would suggest using a [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html). 
With a LinkedHashSet, iterating over the elements will return them in the order they were inserted.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
    hashSet.add("first");
    hashSet.add("second");
    hashSet.add("third");
    for (String s : hashSet) {
        System.out.println(s); // no particular order
    }

    Set<String> linkedHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    linkedHashSet.add("first");
    linkedHashSet.add("second");
    linkedHashSet.add("third");
    for (String s : linkedHashSet) {
        System.out.println(s); // "first", "second", "third"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean insertRecord(Programmer targetProgrammer, List programmerList) {
boolean flag = false;
 for (Programmer p : programmerList){
   if (targetProgrammer.getId() == p.getId()) {
       return true;
}
}
return flag;
}

// Then when you invoke:

Programmer target = new Programmer(1,"Dev","Java");
if (!insertRecord(target, myList)) {
 myList.add(target);
}
```

Comment: Recreating the wheel.  A Set already handles this functionality.

Comment: yes, I know, but in some schools you are asked to work just with ArrayList to begin and you're not allowed to work with other kind of List, Map or Set, so there's a solution using ArrayList if that's the case. Best regards.

Comment: Of course, when that is the case, the point is for the student to do the work for him or herself, in order to learn something. Also, a method "insertRecord()" should probably either insert a record, or be renamed.

Answer (score 0):

What you will be looking for is a `Set`, as a `Set` is a `Collection` that contains no duplicates.

There are a few types that you could use depending on your needs:

- HashSet
- LinkedHashSet
- CopyOnWriteArraySet
- EnumSet
- TreeSet
- ConcurrentSkipListSet

Answer (score -1):

Better use [HashSet](http://way2java.com/collections/hashset-tutorial/) as it takes care of your problem of unique IDs implicitly.   Still better is [SortedSet](http://way2java.com/collections/interface-sortedset/) where you can have the unique elements printed in sorted order automatically.

Comment: at the cost of the overhead of keeping elements sorted.